# loading swf files to buttons all on same page in flash

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

Good day to everyone!Here is my problem to all that is familiar with Flash. I am creating a portfolio using Flash. It has been sometime since using actionscript and can't figure out this. I have 6 different jpeg that I turned into buttons on 1 project page.What I need is to add different swf files to each button and play in seperate window.The code I used first loaded 1 swf file in same window. I am unable to figure out the code to make all 6 buttons show their individual swf file in a seperate window. Please help I am using trial version of the new Flash CC.

Answer (score 0):

Usually, here on StackOverflow we like to see some code indicating you actually tried something, but let me see if I can help anyway.

Sounds like you are asking how to click a button and have the response be to load another swf into a new window.

To do so, you need to reference an html file with a swf embedded in it, since to see a swf in the browser it needs to be in an html page.

So you would do something like the following:

```
import flash.events.MouseEvent;
import flash.external.ExternalInterface;

var myUrl = 'http://www.someSiteWhereMyFilesAre.com/myNewSwf.html';

myButton.addEventListener( MouseEvent.CLICK, onClick );

function onClick( e:MouseEvent ):void
{
    if( ExternalInterface.available )
    {
        ExternalInterface.call( 'window.open', myUrl, '', 'width=400,height=300' );
    }
}
```

That method will only work while you have it online.  It will not load the file locally.

If you do not care about the size of the window that is opened:

Remove the ExternalInterface import.

add imports:

```
import flash.net.URLRequest;
import flash.net.navigateToUrl;
```

Change your onClick function to:

```
function onClick( e:MouseEvent ):void
{
    navigateToURL( new URLRequest( myUrl ), '_blank' );
}
```

Comment: is there away i can do it strickly in flash using flash? i have buttons on one layer and was looking for just a click action on the button so the swf file will show. Is it possible to do that way or does it have to be through dreamweaver or something of that sort?

Comment: Not sure what you mean.  The above method is in Flash, using Flash.

Comment: Hi code that I used on my portfolio. What I am trying to accomplish is that all 6 swf movies play in seperate windows once clicked. This so far brings up only one swf when button is clicked and it is in same window as opposed to being in a separate window. This code doesn't allow me to see the entire swf file as well. Only part because it shows on the portfolio page only and cannot click on other buttons to show swf. I hope that makes sense. Here is the code:

Comment: var loadedSWF:Loader = null;

function loadSWF(file:String, container:MovieClip=null):void
{
    if(container == null) container = MovieClip(root);

    if(loadedSWF != null)
    {
        if(loadedSWF.parent) loadedSWF.parent.removeChild(loadedSWF);
    }

    var req:URLRequest = new URLRequest(file);
    loadedSWF = new Loader();
    loadedSWF.load(req);

    addChild(loadedSWF);
}

cars.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, _click);

function _click(e:MouseEvent):void
{
    loadSWF("cars.swf");
}